# Debug repository coded in plain javascript with github codespaces

Tags: javascript, github, github-codespaces

I am trying to debug a project on github codespace.

However, the node debugger does not stop at the breakpoints.

That's my vscode debug config file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${file}"
        }
    ]
}
```

That the repo: https://github.com/viliusle/miniPaint/

Any suggestions how to debug the above repo?

Thx in advance!

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking about why the Codespaces/debugger isn't working, or how to fix the bug in the repository? Just asking for clarification.

Comment: @LakshyaRaj I would like to debug the mentioned repository. However, the debugger in codespaces does not stop on the breakpoints. Thx for your reply!

Comment: In that case you probably want to include exactly what you're trying to debug ([mre]), and what the error currently *is*. Without that, we won't be able to know what we're trying to answer. I'm actually not an expert in debugging or Codespaces, just trying to figure out this question. An [edit] to your question with the required information would be helpful.